# Why is Selection Sort said to have O(n) swaps?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, selection-sort

I am reading about use cases of Selection Sort, and [this source](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/selection-sort) says:

> (selection sort is used when...) cost of writing to a memory matters like in flash memory (number of writes/swaps is O(n) as compared to O(n2) of bubble sort)

We can even see **O(n^2)** swaps in this example:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. It's going to have 4 swaps, then 3, then 2, and 1. That is **O(n^2)**, not **O(n)** swaps. Why do they say the opposite?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at selection sort - what does your code look like?

Comment: Your count of swaps pertains to bubble sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A selection sort has a time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>), but only O(n) swaps.

In each iteration `i`, you go over all the remaining items (in indexes `i` and onwards), find the right value to populate that index, and swap it there. So in total you perform O(n<sup>2</sup>) **comparisons**, but only O(n) swaps.

Comment: Right. I've messed up the implementation and placed the swap inside the nested for-loop, and it made me think it's O(n^2) swaps. I'll accept the answer.